# What is the difference between std::string and eosio::string?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt

Why should I use eosio::string over std::string? What are the use cases where it would make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [release notes](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases):

> A new type to act as a more efficient replacement to std::string has
>   been added ([#459](https://github.com/eosio/eosio.cdt/pull/459)). eosio::string should be more efficient in memory
>   usage and help to reduce the bloat to smart contract WASMs that
>   std::string imposes.

Where PR 459 references the following string bloat problem:

> Given a minimal smart contract (con.cpp) with a no-op action:
>
> ```
> #include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
>
> class [[eosio::contract]] con : public eosio::contract {
> public:
>     using contract::contract;
>     [[eosio::action]] void act()
>     { }
> };
>
> EOSIO_DISPATCH(con, (act))
> ```
>
> The size of the said contract comes out out to be:
>
> ```
> ~/con $ ll
> total 1
> -rwxrwxr-x   1 i              i        743 2019-03-06 13:37 a.out
> -rw-rw-r--   1 i              i        202 2019-03-06 13:37 con.cpp
> ```
>
> Given a minimal smart contract whilst introducing a std::string:
>
> ```
> #include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
>
> class [[eosio::contract]] con : public eosio::contract {
> public:
>     using contract::contract;
>     [[eosio::action]] void act(const std::string& s)
>     { }
> };
>
> EOSIO_DISPATCH(con, (act))
> ```
>
> The size of the contract is now:
>
> ```
> ~/con $ ll
> total 4
> -rwxrwxr-x   1 i              i        3531 2019-03-06 13:46 a.out
> -rw-rw-r--   1 i              i         222 2019-03-06 13:46 con.cpp
> ```
>
> As is shown, this comes out to an extra 2788 bytes of code-bloat.
>
> This poses to be a problem if a developer were to have many
>   trivial/small smart contracts which utilize a std::string. But if the
>   smart contract is already larger in nature, then this effect is
>   minimal.
>
> Therefore a new string type shall be developed for size optimization.
>   This new string class will implement the small string optimization and
>   provide the normal interface that is provided by std::string but at a
>   fraction of the memory footprint.